# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Custom Membership & Role Entities Not Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing my first ASP.NET MVC 4 project, using C# and Entity Framework and I wish to implement Custom Membership & Roles, using my own SQL Server database and tables.

I have developed two classes, which are called 'CustomMembershipProvider' (inherits MembershipProvider) and 'CustomRoleProvider' (inherits RoleProvider). Both classes seem to work correctly on their first execution but when I manually update fields within SQL Server (e.g. change the Right Name or Right Description), the LINQ query I perform on the Entity appears to be out of date.

For clarity, Roles are controlled within my Rights table (tblRights), which contains field names like 'RightName' and 'RightDescription'.

Below is a sample of the code I execute, which returns a string array containing Role/Right values like "Operator" and "Manager":

```
namespace MyProject.Classes
{
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {

            tblOperator _tblOperator = (from prod in db.tblOperators
                                        where prod.Username == username
                                        select prod).FirstOrDefault();

            var roles = _tblOperator.tblOperatorRights.Where(m => m.WorkCentreID == 1).ToArray();

            return roles.Select(m => m.tblRight.RightName).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Now assuming I manually update SQL Server and change the Role name from "Manager" to "Administrator", the next time this code executes, it will still return "Operator" and "Manager", not "Operator" and "Administrator".

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? You assistance is much appreciated.

Regards, Chris

Comment: Is the value in the database still set to the value you manually updated it to? Are you sure that your connection string is pointing to the correct database?

Comment: You DB context will keep entities in its cache one it has fetched them from the database. You only have 1 context instance per role provider instance. Try instantiating a new context in every call to `GetRolesForUer`, contexts are mean to be used this way.

Comment: @user65439 > The value in the database remains what I set it to.

Comment: @BenRobinson > Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Put `db = new MyEntities();` in your method and remove the initialiser from the field. This way you will get a new context every time, and prevent it serving up cached data.

Comment: @BenRobinson If that solved the problem then add it as an answer and claim the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BenRobinson,

So simple, yet so effective! I am new to C#, so little things like this keep evading me! Thank you! The completed code is below:

```
namespace MyProject.Classes
{
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        private MyEntities db;

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            db = new MyEntities();

            tblOperator _tblOperator = (from prod in db.tblOperators
                                        where prod.Username == username
                                        select prod).FirstOrDefault();

            var roles = _tblOperator.tblOperatorRights.Where(m => m.WorkCentreID == 1).ToArray();

            return roles.Select(m => m.tblRight.RightName).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Regards, Chris

Comment: Assuming that at some point you'll learn dependency injection, I would bookmark the following link: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html